# how to change cursor from pointing hand to an image, when user points to existing image

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage.  On it I display a twitter icon/image.  It is set now so if user clicks on the image it takes them to my twitter page.  I have been trying all I know for days to make so if the user points to the existing image (twitter icon) which currently is a pointing hand, that for that moment of pointing (before clicking) the cursor is not a hand but is another image (for example purposes lets say an image of my face.  currently I have this (which works but does not change cursor):

```
href="https://address of link" &amp;domain= domain name" 
target="_blank" rel="nofollow">
<img src='address of image"' 
style="position: fixed; top: 150px; left:5px; width:50px; height:50px;" 
target="_blank" rel="nofollow"/>
```

I tried adding cursor:url(address of new cursor image), auto:  but nothing.

Of course I only want the new cursor image to be for this one time use, then to return to pointer for the rest of the webpage.

Comment: Can you share your code

Answer (score 0):

```css
button:hover {
  cursor: url('http://example.com/cursor.png'), default !important;
}
```

```html
<button id='button'>Your Image Here! Don't Forget The Id!</button>
```

This will change the cursor to an image when you hover over an image. Don't forget to use the id (HTML) and the URL (CSS).